# How do you initialize a list of feedItem on creation?

Tags: apex, list

I've been having a hard time finding an answer to this question. How when you instantiate a list of FeedItem, do you manually initialize that list with more than one item at a time?

So far this is what I've came up with. I'm not sure its the best way though.

```
feedItemList = new List<FeedItem>{
            new FeedItem(
            Body = 'this is a test in chatter group bug', 
            ParentId = chatterParent.id,
            Type = 'TextPost',
            Status = 'published'),
            new FeedItem(Body = 'this is a test in chatter group without a bug', 
            ParentId = chatterParent.id,
            Type = 'TextPost',
            Status = 'published'),
            new FeedItem(Body = 'this is a test with case parent and with a bug not in a chatter group bug', 
            ParentId = generalParentItem.Id,
            Type = 'TextPost',
            Status = 'published'), 
            new FeedItem(Body = 'this is a test with case parent and without a bug not in a chatter group bug', 
            ParentId = generalParentItem.Id,
            Type = 'TextPost',
            Status = 'published')
    };
```

any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: What you wrote is fine, but normally we only need to do that in Unit tests.

Comment: Thanks Zaitsman, that's exactly what I'm doing. I appreciate you letting me know.